# Resizing NSPopover flickers in 10.14

Tags: macos, flicker, nspopover

I have a popover which i want to resize the popover whenever click action performed. In `viewDidLayout` using `preferredContentSize` i am resizing the popover

```
- (void)viewDidLayout {
    self.preferredContentSize = NSMakeSize(NSWidth(tableview.frame), height);
}
```

this is working fine  below 10.14 but in 10.14 there is flickering
what could be the reason

Any help or suggestions would be more appreciated.